# UIButton Subclass can't assign target - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift4

I have looked at various other answers to similar question, and followed the advice given there, but here I am getting no errors, but the target function never runs.

I have this UIButton subclass

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

var buttonColour: UIColor = UIColor.red
var height: CGFloat = 0
var width: CGFloat = 0
var text: String = ""
var x: CGFloat = 0
var y: CGFloat = 0

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

init(frame: CGRect, colour: UIColor, height: CGFloat, text: String, width: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.buttonColour = colour
    self.height = height
    self.text = text
    self.width = width
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    setUpView()
}



func setUpView() {
    let roundedButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    roundedButton.backgroundColor = buttonColour
    roundedButton.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
    roundedButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    roundedButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    roundedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.wasPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.addSubview(roundedButton)
}



@objc func wasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("was pressed")
}

}
```

And I call it like this:

```
let addReview = RoundedButton(frame: CGRect(), colour: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9921568627, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1), height: 48, text: "Review", width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16, x: 8, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 56)
                self.view.addSubview(addReview)
```

However the wasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) function never prints 'was pressed'. Does anyone know why this maybe?

Also is it possible to add the target such that it would call a 'dynamic' target in the superclass. 
E.g I can send the subclass a different target each time.

This is so that I can use this RoundedButton class to make multiple buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add another button inside `func setUpView()` as you already inside the   button subclass so configure it's properties directly , all the properties you declare are already exists in the button

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, colour: UIColor, text: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = colour
        self.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.wasPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func wasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("was pressed")
    }

}
```

//

```
let addReview = RoundedButton(frame: CGRect(x:8,y:UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 56,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16, height: 48), colour: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9921568627, green: 0.6941176471, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1), text: "Review" )
self.view.addSubview(addReview)
```